# API Error Code: 191 (using ASP.Net)

Tags: facebook

Guys here is my configuration for my facebook app, please tell me if I'm missing anything:

Basic Info-------------
App Namespace: footygo
App Domain: footygo.com

Website----------------
Site URL: http://**www.footygo.com**

App on Facebook-------
Canvas URL: http://**www.footygo.com/canvas/**
Secure Canvas URL: https://**www.footygo.com/canvas/**
Canvas Page: http://**apps.facebook.com/footygo**

My application contains a folder named Canvas/ which contains all the facebook pages. The Canvas folder contains two files at the moment, namely: Default.aspx and Setup.aspx

Within my web.config file, I have set the following information:
PostAuthorizeRedirectURL="Setup.aspx" 
I also tried varying with PostAuthorizeRedirectURL="Canvas/Setup.aspx" to no avail.

I am consistently getting the following error message:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

What is the issue? Do you guys have any ideas? This is my first facebook app, and it's not working out as I thought it would :(

Thank you for your time and patience, and sorry if this question has already been posted numerous times. I went through most (but not all) of the 191 error questions but couldn't find anything of value.

Please let me know if you have any idea about what's going on. My release date is less than 24 hours away!

Humble Regards,
Rowan R.

Comment: I feel your pain with the first Facebook app. It is quite a learning curve :) It gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full URL. The redirect_uri must be within the same domain name as what is listed in the settings in Facebook.

```
PostAuthorizeRedirectURL="http://www.footygo.com/canvas/Setup.aspx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Adam!

However I figured out what was wrong and got it to work! It wasn't the PostAuthorizeRedirectURL, it was actually the URL I was using to access my app!

I was accessing my app using https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx where xxxxxxx is my app's id. That did not work (at first). I then tried accessing my app using it's app name, i.e. https://apps.facebook.com/xyz and it worked!

All I can say is... the facebook platform sucks.